# Redmine Docker Erases Existing Database and Files On Reboot

Tags: mysql, docker-compose, redmine

I'm migrating an old Redmine server to a new dockerized environment.  I have a separate volume that stores the state.  I launched Redmine with the docker-compose -f stack.yml up (shown below).  I successfully imported the database, and everything was working as it should.

To make sure it would all be working correctly after a reboot, I rebooted the host machine (AWS instance)  I did not do a docker-compose down first.  Afterwards, the Redmine containers were running again, but they were different/new/fresh containers, and they had erased the files and database.  That is, the volumes were still mounted, per stack.yml, but the services seemed to re-initialize and clear all existing data.

```
version: '3.1'

services:

redmine:
  image: redmine
  restart: always
  ports:
    - 80:3000
  environment:
    REDMINE_DB_MYSQL: db
    #REDMINE_DB_USERNAME: defaults to root
    REDMINE_DB_PASSWORD: password
    REDMINE_SECRET_KEY_BASE: secret
  volumes:
    - /mnt/xvdf/files:/usr/src/redmine/files:Z

db:
  image: mysql:5.7
  restart: always
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    MYSQL_DATABASE: redmine
  volumes:
    - /mnt/xvdf/mysql:/var/lib/mysql:Z
    - /mnt/xvdf:/mnt/xvdf:Z
```

I tried committing the images and then running those first, but the same thing happened.

How do I tell Redmine Docker image, "You're not new.  Use what is already here."?

Or is it something else?  What's weird is that it does not clear all the files from the files directory on the first up.  That is, on the first docker-compose up, files directory is mounted the same way, but files remain.  docker-compose down, up, start, stop, and restart all keep the files in place and work as expected.

Is there something about running sudo shutdown -r now?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the volume mount was not remounting on reboot, because I forgot to fstab it.  Rookie mistake, I know.

The files were not deleted.  Because of this, the containers actually found empty directories and initialized them.  Had the containers found something there, they would have used it.